# Questions closed as 'non constructive' may become constructive

Tags: discussion

So while reviewing the lovely reopen queue, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301389/why-does-one-use-dependency-injection) about Dependency Injection

So it was closed originally as "non-constructive" and possibly not a good fit for SO...

Since it was closed, it has been viewed >180,000 times, gained more than 400 up votes, and has 5 highly up-voted answers (2 of them with 400+ up votes)...

Is there a case for questions like this that were viewed originally as not constructive having **become** constructive over the last 5 years?

what does the community think of this?

I think this is the kind of question that has dragged thousands of viewers to SO from Google, so it definitely has value...

In this case, more answers that may add something are prevented because it's closed.

Comment: wow, 3 downvotes already, in <10 seconds, impressive... with no viewpoints or opinions...

Comment: [Voting on meta is different](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Votes are often used to express (dis)agreement with the general premise of the Meta question. These votes won't affect your mainsite reputation.

Comment: If you can't explain why the close reason doesn't actually apply to the question, why would you expect people to think it doesn't merit closure?  The fact that people have viewed and voted on a question doesn't mean that it's sufficiently narrowly scoped, not opinion based, or having any of the other issues brought up in the close reason.  If you want people explaining why your position is wrong, you need to *have explained a position to begin with*.

Comment: The question is off topic, but before it was closed, some actually useful answers were generated. The closure preserves the useful answers that are there, while keeping the issue of the opinion based question (The fact that they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam) at bay since people won't be able to add new answers. It's a win-win to be closed.

Comment: see also: [Suggestions for editing old “Not constructive” question into constructiveness so that it can be preserved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141006/165773) (at MSE)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While there are some awesome answers in there, the question is still **too broad** and / or **opinion based**.

There is no reason to re-open it. It doesn't need *more* answers, and the closure doesn't prevent votes on existing answers or the question.